# Vista install from DVD hangs on green loading progress bar

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, installation

I have a HP TouchSmart IQ700 that needed the SATA hard disk replacing. With a brand new formatted hard disk I inserted the Windows Vista x64 DVD and it starts to load.

It gets past the Loading Files screen (black screen, white progress bar) and the next screen changes to the Microsoft green progress bar and it hangs. I have left it for well over 30 minutes to make sure.

This hangs before I get any install menus/GUI for installing Windows Vista.

All peripherals are disconnected and the BIOS has very limited options. I have disabled power management and there are no USB options at all (was looking for the disable legacy USB).

The only item connected is the wireless keyboard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mentioned USB in your question - are you booting with a USB DVD-ROM drive?  Or is it a SATA DVD-ROM drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called HP and they recommend wiping the disk using DelDisk then retry the recovery disks.  I have not tried this yet but think it probably wont work because I tried a brand new clean hard disk.  I will report back shortly.

**EDIT: The problem was the motherboard and CPU.  Replaced both and all was fine.**

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make sure you are using a good install CD. I've seen installs stop like that if a file is corrupted. Check the disk on another system to see if it boots/installs properly, or re-burn the disk at a lower speed.

Other than that, try to remove each peripheral one by one and see if it lets you past that screen. Replace wireless keyboard with a trusty wired one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am using an original Vista Home Premium OEM disk.  It works fine on another computer but fails on this.  I think it is something to do with the SATA hard disk and vista.  I installed Windows XP without a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when trying to rebuild a computer. It turned out that my motherboard was missing the primary SATA port and once the motherboard was replaced, the OS loaded with no issues. check you SATA ports on your motherboard to ensure they arent loose.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worth inspecting the install disc for dirt.

I would replace both SATA cables (optical drive and hard drive), or at least unseat them and reseat them if you don't have spares.